# XML validation with XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I try to validate my xml structure, using an xml schema.

This code sample is given here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-5.0

```
 XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.contoso.com/books", "contosoBooks.xsd");
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("contosoBooks.xml", settings);
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(reader);

        ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

        // the following call to Validate succeeds.
        document.Validate(eventHandler);

        // add a node so that the document is no longer valid
        XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
        navigator.MoveToFollowing("price", "http://www.contoso.com/books");
        XmlWriter writer = navigator.InsertAfter();
        writer.WriteStartElement("anotherNode", "http://www.contoso.com/books");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Close();

        // the document will now fail to successfully validate
        document.Validate(eventHandler);
```

Problem is that when I'm using a non valide xml document, I already have an exception of type System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException on line :

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("contosoBooks.xml", settings);
```

Does this mean you dont need to use this Validate(eventHandler) method with C# 6 anymore ? Or will it take care of few specific validation problems ?

Comment: I'm using .net framework

Comment: An older version : v4.0.X  :)

Comment: There are two types of validation for an xml file 1) Structure 2) Contents.  Check if values are within an acceptable range.   You are failing the first test.  Schema test second check.

Comment: @jdweng So, a non-well-formed document would lead to `XmlReader.Create` throwing a `XmlSchemaValidationException` ? - I would have expected a different one.

Comment: You can fix except with XmlReader by using following :             XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("uri", settings);

Comment: document.Load(reader); is actually throwing a XmlSchemaException,